# How to play youtube videos in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, video, youtube

I tried the following code to play videos this works on Chrome, mozila and safari but not on IE. Can you please let me know how to play the video on IE.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br /><br /><br />

<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" autostart="true" >

<br /><br /><br />

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you [enable iframes](https://techhelpkb.com/enable-iframes/)?

Comment: Yes i Enablled.
Select "Internet Options"
Click the "Security" tab, select the "Internet" icon, and click the "Custom Level" button.
Scroll down to the "Miscellaneous" section, find the "Launching programs and files in an Iframe" entry & click the "Enable" button.
Close all open Dialogs by clicking their OK button.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML5 extract has three videos - the first two will play on IE (make sure iFrames is enabled as Secespitus says but it usually is by default) and the last one should not play on any browser.

The three videos are inserted into the page by:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The second one by:

```html
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" autostart="true" >
```

and the third one by:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myS7iZg2WzY" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This last one will not play as the source you have set if to a web page containing the video, rather than to the video itself.

If you just want to embed the video itself then the first embed line should work.

Comment: I enabled iFrame on IE but video is not playing. I followed the below steps on IE.
Select "Internet Options"
Click the "Security" tab, select the "Internet" icon, and click the "Custom Level" button.

Scroll down to the "Miscellaneous" section, find the "Launching 
programs and files in an Iframe" entry & click the "Enable" button.
Close all open Dialogs by clicking their OK button.

Comment: If you are able to share the link to your web page, we can check it? Failing that if you can capture the browser console and share that it may help - right click on your browse and select inspect element and then click on the console tab.